# Recursividade - adicionar números em um array

Tags: javascript, recursão

Estou fazendo o curso da FreeCodeCamp e no assunto de recursividade me deparei com esse código:

```
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
```

Ele me retorna um array com correspondente ao tamanho N (se eu colocar `5`, retorna um array `[1,2,3,4,5]`).

Eu entendo o conceito de recursividade, mas não consegui entender esse código. Porque o `const countArray = countup(n - 1);`? Qual o significado dessa linha? Porque pra mim, a partir do momento que eu chamo a função `countup(n - 1)`, o que esta abaixo dela não é executado. Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Depois que você chama `countup(n - 1)`, as linhas abaixo são executadas sim, mas **só depois que esta chamada retorna**.

Para simplificar, vamos ver o que acontece quando você chama `countup(2)`:

- `countup(2)`: `n` é igual a 2, então não entra no `if (n < 1)`
- é chamado `countup(n - 1)`, ou seja, `countup(1)`

  - dentro da chamada `countup(1)`: `n` é igual a 1, então não entra no `if (n < 1)`
  - é chamado `countup(n - 1)`, ou seja, `countup(0)`

    - dentro da chamada `countup(0)`: `n` é igual a 0, então entra no `if (n < 1)` e retorna um array vazio (`[]`)
  - `countup(0)` retornou o array vazio, que foi colocado na variável `countArray` (é o que a linha `const countArray = countup(n - 1)` faz)
  - `countArray.push(n)`: aqui `n` vale 1, então 1 é colocado no array (que agora é `[ 1 ]`)
  - o array `[ 1 ]` é retornado
- `countup(1)` retornou o array `[ 1 ]`, que é colocado na variável `countArray`
- `countArray.push(n)`: aqui `n` vale 2, então 2 é colocado no array (que passa a ser `[ 1, 2 ]`)
- o array `[ 1, 2 ]` é retornado

Ou seja, a primeira chamada começa no valor inicial de `n` (no exemplo acima foi `2`), e a cada chamada recursiva ele vai diminuindo, até chegar a zero. Quando chega a zero, ela retorna o array vazio e o processo começa a "voltar", inserindo os números no array e retornando-o para a chamada anterior.

O que pode confundir é que a cada chamada o contexto muda: o valor de `n` e o array `countArray` sendo manipulados têm valores diferentes. Mas no fim tudo "se junta" e o resultado é um array contendo todos os números de 1 a `n`.

O importante é que o fato de fazer uma chamada recursiva não trava a execução, como você imagina. O que acontece é que uma chamada recursiva pode acabar fazendo outras chamadas recursivas (como quando `countup(2)` chamou `countup(1)`, que por sua vez chamou `countup(0)`), e essas chamadas ficam "penduradas" esperando as outras retornarem. E depois que elas retornam, a execução continua nas linhas seguintes.

O que garante que esse processo não dura para sempre é a condição de parada (`if (n < 1)`), pois é quando não é feita mais nenhuma chamada recursiva.

---

#### Para ententer recursão, antes precisa entender recursão

Pode ser que ajude se você pensar na definição da solução de maneira recursiva: como eu crio um array contendo os números de 1 a `N`?

1. se `N` < 1, o intervalo de 1 a `N` não terá nenhum número, então o array é vazio (é o que o `if` faz)
2. se `N` >= 1 (ou seja, o bloco `else`):

   - 2.a) crio um array contendo os números de 1 a `N - 1` (usando este mesmo algoritmo recursivamente, ou seja, volto para o passo 1, mas usando o valor de `N - 1`)
   - 2.b) adiciono o `N` nesse array

O passo 2.a corresponde a `const countArray = countup(n - 1)` (eu resolvo o mesmo problema recursivamente para `N - 1`), e o passo 2.b corresponde a `countArray.push(n)`.

A ideia de recursão é basicamente essa: existe um caso "base" com uma solução trivial (o array vazio), e para os outros casos você resolve instâncias menores do problema de maneira recursiva, até chegar ao caso base, e no final junta tudo.

---

#### Explicando de outra maneira

Devido a [esta dúvida nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/439285/recursividade-adicionar-n%c3%bameros-em-um-array/439290#comment848340_439290), vou tentar explicar de forma um pouco mais detalhada. Para simplificar, vamos supor que eu chamei `countup(1)`.

É feita a chamada a `countup(1)`:

- aqui o `n` vale 1, por isso não entra no `if (n < 1)`
- dentro do bloco `else`:

  - `const countArray = countup(n - 1);` **←** como `n` vale 1, então é feita a chamada para `countup(0)`

Aqui fazemos uma pausa para explicar que a chamada a `countup(0)` é "independente" da chamada a `countup(1)`. Apesar de ser a mesma função, e de ser chamada dentro dela mesma, são duas chamadas diferentes e cada uma executa de acordo com o seu contexto (no caso, o valor que é passado como parâmetro é diferente).

Então a chamada `countup(1)` está executando a linha `const countArray = countup(n - 1);`. Isso quer dizer que ela precisa pegar o retorno de `countup(0)` e atribuir o valor retornado na variável `countArray`. Ou seja, ela precisa esperar `countup(0)` executar por completo.

E como `countup(0)` executa? Assim:

- `n` vale 0, por isso entra no  `if (n < 1)` e retorna um array vazio (`[]`)

Como `countup(0)` já terminou (retornando um array vazio), então `countup(1)` pode continuar executando de onde parou:

```
const countArray = countup(n - 1);
```

Nesta linha ela pega o retorno de `countup(0)` (o array vazio) e atribui este valor na variável `countArray`. Depois ela executa as linhas seguintes:

```
countArray.push(n);
return countArray;
```

Ou seja, ela adiciona `n` ao array (e como estamos dentro da chamada `countup(1)`, o `n` vale 1, portanto o número 1 será adicionado ao `countArray`).
E por fim, `countArray` (que agora é o array `[1]`) é retornado, e `countup(1)` encerra sua execução.

Repare que cada chamada a `countup` é "independente": só porque uma está no `if`, não quer dizer que outra não pode estar no `else` (pois cada uma tem um contexto diferente, já que os valores de `n` que cada uma recebe é diferente). E só porque uma delas retornou, não quer dizer que as outras devem retornar imediatamente: cada uma retorna só quando chega em alguma linha contendo `return`.

---

De maneira similar, quando chamamos `countup(2)`:

- aqui o `n` vale 2, por isso não entra no `if (n < 1)`
- dentro do bloco `else`:

  - `const countArray = countup(n - 1);` **←** como `n` vale 2, então é feita a chamada para `countup(1)`

Ou seja, a chamada `countup(2)` precisa esperar `countup(1)` terminar para atribuir o retorno na variável `countArray`.

E pela explicação acima, já sabemos que `countup(1)` retorna o array `[1]`. Ou seja, depois que `countup(1)` termina, o array `[1]` é retornado e atribuído na variável `countArray`.

Depois disso, a chamada `countup(2)` pode continuar executando. A linha seguinte é `countArray.push(n);`, e como `countArray` é `[1]` e o `n` vale 2, o número 2 é adicionado no array, que passa a ser `[1, 2]`.

Depois disso o array é retornado, e o resultado é `[1, 2]`.

Comment: 'dentro da chamada countup(0): n é igual a 0, então entra no if (n < 1) e retorna um array vazio ([])'

Se ele retorna um array vazio, o certo não seria SAIR da função? Porque o ELSE é executado se ele somente é feito para ser executado se o IF for falso? O que quero dizer é: se o IF for verdadeiro, então o ELSE não é executado. Ai que estou em duvida tambem.  

E pra ser bem sincero e peço até desculpas porque sua resposta é extremamente completa, a partir deste tópico que eu coloquei eu realmente nao entendi

Comment: @BrunoValle Não, ele só sai da função se tivesse um `return countup(0)`. Mas como vc guarda o retorno em uma variável (`countArray = countup(0)`), o retorno é guardado na variável e a execução continua. Não sei se ajuda, mas imagine que em vez de `countup` vc chamasse uma outra função qualquer (`countArray = outrafuncao(n - 1)`), a função `countup` retornaria ou continuaria na linha seguinte? O fato de chamar a mesma função é só um detalhe, pois ela será chamada novamente e cada chamada é "independente". Não sei se isso confundiu mais ainda ou ajudou...

Comment: Ou seja, `countup(0)` retorna o array vazio e essa chamada se encerra. Mas `countup(0)` foi chamado dentro da execução de `countup(1)` (e essa ainda não se encerrou, pois ela está dentro do else e precisa continuar nas linhas seguintes)

Comment: @BrunoValle countup(1) entra no else e chama countup(0). E countup(0) entra no if e retorna o array vazio. A execução de countup(0) encerrou, mas countup(1) ainda não, pois ela ainda precisa executar o resto (atribui o retorno de countup(0) na variável countArray, faz o push e o return). Cada chamada de countup é independente, o fato de uma estar no if não impede a outra de estar no else

Comment: @BrunoValle Atualizei a resposta, adicionei uma explicação mais detalhada no final. Veja se ajudou a entender melhor

Comment: @BrunoValle Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis. Quanto a ser professor, hmmm, acho que não (é uma profissão muito mal valorizada e geralmente não compensa o stress todo) :-)

Comment: Eu entendi! Tudo esta dentro das chamadas independentes! Porém, quando n = 2, em que momento ele subtrai o n para colocar o 1 e em seguida o numero 2 no array?

Comment: Eu entendi que até a parte que é retornado um array para countArray e em seguida a função segue seu fluxo normalmente. Porem, ao colocar, por exemplo, o numero 2 no N, o correto seria inserir o numero 2 no array, não?

Comment: @BrunoValle `countup(2)` vai entrar no `else` e chamar `const countArray = countup(1)` (e pela explicação acima, já sabemos que `countup(1)` chama `countup(0)` e no fim retorna `[1]`). Então depois que `countup(1)` retorna, a variável `countArray` (dentro da chamada `countup(2)`) é `[1]`. Depois ela chama o `push` e adiciona o 2 no array (o `push` só é chamado depois que `countup(1)` retorna), e o resultado é `[1, 2]` - Ou seja, `countup(2)` insere o 2 no array, mas só depois que `countup(1)` retorna

Comment: @BrunoValle Adicionei essa explicação no final da resposta

Answer (score 1):

Veja que cada vez que o `countup` é chamado dentro dele mesmo, o interpretador
aguarda até que a função retorne um valor para que ele possa prosseguir com a execução do código.

Para facilitar o entendimento acompanhe o cenário abaixo e leia os comentários dentro do código.

Considere `countup(2)`:

Primeira execução:

```
function countup(2) {
    if (2 < 1) {
        return [];
    } else {
        // O interpretador vai parar aqui até que a função
        // retorne seu valor...veja o Segunda execução
        const countArray = countup(2 - 1);
        countArray.push(n);
        return countArray;
    }
}
```

Segunda execução

```
function countup(1) {
    if (1 < 1) {
        return [];
    } else {
        // O interpretador vai parar aqui até que a função
        // retorne seu valor...veja o Terceira execução
        const countArray = countup(1 - 1);
        countArray.push(n);
        return countArray;
    }
}
```

Terceira execução

```
function countup(0) {
    if (0 < 1) {
        // Para o valor 0 esta função irá retornar um array vazio.
        // Este resultado será recebido na segunda execução
        return [];
    } else {
        const countArray = countup(0 - 1);
        countArray.push(n);
        return countArray;
    }
}
```

Voltando a segunda execução

```
function countup(1) {
    if (1 < 1) {
        return [];
    } else {
        // Agora com o resultado na mão da terceira execução o 
        // interpretador irá prosseguir até o return
        const countArray = [] /* countup(1 - 1) = [] */;
        countArray.push(n); // Agora o array vazio ganha o valor 1 = [1]
        return countArray;
    }
}
```

Voltando a primeira execução

```
function countup(2) {
    if (2 < 1) {
        return [];
    } else {
        // Agora com o resultado na mão da segunda execução o 
        // interpretador irá prosseguir até o return
        const countArray = [1] // countup(2 - 1) = [1];
        countArray.push(n); // O array ganha o novo valor 2: [1, 2]
        return countArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Marcelo, muito obrigado pela explicação!!! Sou novo aqui e estava com receio de mandar perguntas. Mais uma vez, obrigado!

Comment: Grande @BrunoValle, fico feliz em ajudar ;) e sempre que tiver dúvidas não hesite em postar. abs

Answer (score 0):

Quando `N < 1` (primeira condição), a recursividade vai começar a voltar. 
Ou seja, na linha que você está em dúvida `const countArray = countup(n - 1);`, o método irá retornar 0, portanto `const countArray = 0`. A partir disso, irá executar as linhas de baixo:

```
countArray.push(n);
return countArray;
```

Ou seja, N será adicionado ao array na **volta da recursividade**. Se você colocar essas linhas antes de `countArray = countup(n - 1);`, o array retornará como `[5,4,3,2,1]`, pois você estará adicionando `n` ao array antes de chegar no início da contagem.

Comment: Vitor, muito obrigado!!